# Python regular expression not returning all groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

`<hello<world<1 \< 2>`, which represents a list of three strings `"hello", "world", "1 < 2"`. I want my regular expression to be able to match `("hello", "world", "1 \< 2")`. (I will remove the backslashes later in evaluation). I'm using the following regular expression to match the text:

```
r"(?:<((?:[^<>]|\\.)*))+>"
```

The way I understand it, it matches at least one (`<` with any number of non-`<>` or `\anything` after it) and then a closing `>`, but the results do not suggest that. Using `re.match(..., ...).groups()`, I get the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"(?:<((?:[^<>]|\\.)*))+>", r"<hello<world<1 \< 2>").groups()
<<< (' 2',)
>>> re.match(r"(?:<((?:[^<>]|\\.)*))+>", r"<hello<world<1 \< 2>").group(0)
<<< '<hello<world<1 \\< 2>'
```

What's confusing is that `group(0)` isn't even in `groups()`, and it appears that the rest of the substrings aren't in `group(...)`. Is something wrong with my regular expression or approach, and how should I fix it?

To be clear, I'm building a lexer for a golfing language using regex, so replacing it with something like a char-by-char lexer would be inconvenient since I already have the regular expression lexer and most of the expressions set up. I'm wondering if a pure regex solution is possible.

Comment: How about just splitting by `<`? `re.split(r"(?<!\\)<", r"<hello<world<1 \< 2>")`

Comment: @Psidom Doesn't work for the backslashed `<`... though I could try using a non-capturing match for something non-backslash before it. I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @Psidom Hey that actually works beautifully. Thanks! Can you post an answer so I can upvote your approach?

Comment: Which one works? I guess a plain split doesn't work if you don't want to split on `\<`.

Comment: @Psidom I managed to do `re.split(r"(?=[^\\])<", text)` on the match but the one you offer works nicely for my purposes; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
s = "<hello<world<1 \< 2>"
import re
l = [i for i in re.split("\<(?!\s\d)|\>", s) if i]
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'world', '1 \\< 2']
```

Comment: The slight problem with this answer is that `<<>` should give `["", ""]`. Rather than `if i` I'd probably just do `re.split("...", s)[1:-1]`.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I am not sure if I understand the context of that issue. Could you post the string that contains `<<>` and what your desired output is?

Comment: No like your approach will remove all empty strings (the ones at the beginning and end) but if I set `s = "<<>"`, I expect `l = ["", ""]` whereas your answer would give `[]` because empty strings are removed.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino You could use the `[]` to your advantage by checking for it and if it is indeed found, proceed to the part of the lexer that will handle a empty statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the part of the lexer that will handle an empty statement... replacing your last line with `l = re.split("\<(?!\s\d)|\>", s)[1:-1]` does literally exactly what I want...

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I apologize, I misunderstood the problem. I am glad `l = re.split("\<(?!\s\d)|\>", s)[1:-1]`. If